# want to fetch data from database and display it in html file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fetch-api

I am done it fetching data from data base and store in object in my node js file but  I can't able to sent that object to my Clint JavaScript file.
I try 2-3 way but I can't access my object in javascript file;
yes I don't want to do it by .ejs file I have to do some operation with 'data' in javascript file.

```js
app.post('/submit-rowmatrial', (req, res) => {
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'username',
password: 'password',
database: 'mydb'
});

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
const tagId = req.params.id;
// console.log(tagId)
if (tagId !== 'manage-stock') return;
const sql = 'select  itam_name,sum(quantity) as value_sum from raw_materials group by      itam_name';
let connection = create_conection();
connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
if (err) throw err;
// store the result in a variable
data = result;
connection.end((err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Connection closed!');
});
res.json(data);
});
});
```

**>! now I'm trying to fetch data in javascript file**

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3002/manage-stock')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
console.log(data);
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
let ob = data[i];
let values = Object.values(ob);
iteam_name=values[0];
quantity=values[1];
console.log(iteam_name+" -> "+quantity);
}
})
```

Comment: Aside: `app.post` isn't closed. You should format your code properly so you can see the problems more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few changes in the code

```js
app.post('/submit-rowmatrial', (req, res) => {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydb',
  });
});
```

this is the first section. Here the connection variable is only limited to the first app.post() callback.

A better way to handle database connection is to create a separate global variable or export it from a completely different module. Also it is far better to create a new connection pool instead of just a connection which connects and disconnects repeatedly for every query.

```js
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  database: 'dbName',
  password: 'root',
  host:'localhost',
  user: 'root',
});

const db = pool.promise();
```

Use this db object to make queries.

Now, in the second part of the code where `app.get('/:id')`

`if (tagId !== 'manage-stock') return;` in this statement, even if you want to exit out of the function, you need to return some data back to the client, else the client will wait forever.

so instead,

```js
if (tagId !== 'manage-stock'){
    return res.json({
        message:'tag id is not manage-stock',
    });
};
```

then continue with the rest of the code.

`const sql = 'select itam_name,sum(quantity) as value_sum from raw_materials group by itam_name';`

Use the `db` object to execute query

```js
db.execute(sql)
  .then((data)=>{
     // data is an array of multiple objects along with the 
     // data fetched from the database and other related metadata.
     // the actual table data is present as the first element of data array
     // you can always console.log(data) to get a glimpse of what it is
     // returning.
     console.log(data);
     console.log(data[0]);
     return res.json(data[0]);
   })
  .catch((err)=>{
    throw err;
    // however you want to handle the error
  })
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if this worked out for you. It motivates us to answer more and more queries on the platform